# Using Variable name as object title

Tags: php, javascript, html

Here is my code currently in javascript:

```
    'methv': document.getElementById("methv").value,
    'q1': document.getElementById("q1").value,
    'q2':document.getElementById("q2").value,
    'q3':document.getElementById("q3").value,
    'q4':document.getElementById("q4").value,
    'comm':document.getElementById("comm").value,
```

in my php file i have a invisible input field named num which has a value of a unique number in my database.

```
<input id="num" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post['unique person code']; ?>" />
```

is there a way to have this value as a variable name with this. For example it will have these values :

'q1' + num : document.getElementById("q1").value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Use bracket notation:

```
containerObject['q1' + num] = document.getElementById("q1").value;
```

Where container object is whatever contains all of your data. `num` would have to be defined first although.